# Can't get https://github.com/steevelefort/cordova3-ios-tts-plugin to work

Tags: android, ios, cordova, build, text-to-speech

I'm trying to implement TTS to my Phonegap App (I'm using PhoneGap Build) without success: i can't get the built App up to `speak` (by speak i mean convert text to speech)

I'm using https://github.com/steevelefort/cordova3-ios-tts-plugin because it is supposed to work for Android and iOS.

I'm using the following code to Test (placed under the header tags):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  ttsPlugin.initTTS();
  ttsPlugin.speak("Welcome");
</script>
```

I also added the following to my config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="com.lefortsoftware.ttsplugin" version="0.1.0" />
```

In theory, the App should read out loud "Welcome", but it doesn't.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: No one can tell you what you did wrong because you haven't told anyone what problem you are having.

Comment: Hi rmaddy, Steeve already answered my question... i added more text to make it more clear to others. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this plugin several months ago to code a little game for my kids.
It's not supposed to be a production plugin.

Nevertheless, there are some things you need to verify :

1. Like all plugins, you must wait the "deviceready" event before
   running " initTTS".
2. "initTTS" method takes a "successCallback"
   function. In your example, you don't use it, so, you try to use TTS
   before init.

Comment: Hi Steeve, thank you for your reply, i forgot to update the question. Running ttsPlugin.initTTS(); in deviceready fixed my problem. Thanks!